# c++ binary search tree by using dereference

Tags: c++, insert, binary-search-tree

Hello I tried to use deference to insert node to a binary search tree. But I think now I am stuck in the insert function now. I think I made some mistake when recall the insert function. So anyone can help to tell me what's wrong with my code, thank you.

```
struct BstNode {
    int data;
    BstNode *left;
    BstNode *right;
};


BstNode *GetNewNode(int);

void Insert(BstNode **, int);

void Insert(BstNode **root, int data)
{
    if(*root == NULL){
        *root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    else if(data <= root){
        Insert(*(root -> left), data);
    }
    else {
        Insert(*(root -> right), data);
}

BstNode *GetNewNode(int data)  
{
    BstNode *newNode = new BstNode(); 
    newNode->data = data; 
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

int main ()
{
    BstNode *root = NULL; 

    Insert(&root,15);
    Insert(&root,10);
    Insert(&root,20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "stuck"?  Compiler errors?  Program runs but never stops?  Can't figure out how to write the code?

Comment: @Shawn W W  This condition else if(data <= root){ does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is the following

```
void Insert( BstNode **root, int data )
{
    if ( not *root ) 
    {
        *root = GetNewNode( data );
    }
    else if ( data < ( *root )->data ) 
    {
        Insert( &( *root )->left, data );
    }
    else 
    {
        Insert( &( *root )->right, data );
    }
}
```

Compare the syntax of conditions in this function with the syntax of conditions in your function's implementation and all will be clear.

For example this if statement has at least two errors

```
else if(data <= root){
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^  
        Insert(*(root -> left), data);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and the compiler will issue corresponding diagnostic messages.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.  But I wonder what is the meaning of               
   &(*root)->left   in here. Take the address of the pointer? I am confused. And why here need two * before the root in the Insert function. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ShawnWW To change a pointer to an original node you have to pass it by reference that is by using a pointer to pointer. Otherwise the function will be deal with a copy of the original node.

Comment: Thanks, so can you help to explain what is the  &(*root)->left meaning?

Comment: @ShawnWW It is the address of the left node of the current node.